# angular not wrapping text correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

## intro

I am creating a simple project in angular and using angular material with flexlayout

### problem

the problem is that it doesn't wrap the text correctly on smaller screens, it either clips text or just make it larger than the container.

### code

#### html

```
 <div class="container">

    <h2>Normal</h2>
    <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column wrap">
        <div class="child-1">1. One</div>
        <div class="child-2">2. Two</div>
        <div class="child-3">3. Three</div>
    </div>

    <h2>Default</h2>
    <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column wrap">
        <div class="child-1" fxFlex>
            <p>1. One</p>
            <p>166.67px</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child-2" fxFlex>
            <p>1. Two</p>
            <p>166.67px</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child-3" fxFlex>
            <p>1. Three</p>
            <p>166.67px</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>fxFlex with grow shrink values</h2>
    <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column wrap">
        <div class="child-1" fxFlex="2 1 auto">
            <p> Angular fxFlex flexgrow flexshrink flexbasis</p>
            <p>250px</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child-2" fxFlex>
            <p>Angular fxFlex flexgrow flexshrink flexbasis</p>
            <p>125px</p>
        </div>
        <div class="child-3" fxFlex>
            <p>125px</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
        <mat-list>
            <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column wrap">
                <mat-list-item fxFlex>
                        <div mat-line> <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias qui assumenda perferendis atque ipsa ipsum enim voluptate voluptas mollitia autem minima deleniti quisquam iste alias, accusantium, eveniet ut, rerum totam.</p></div>
                </mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item fxFlex>
                    <div mat-line>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos molestiae, sequi fugiat tempora dicta numquam ipsam dolorem natus ducimus et expedita cum quaerat porro, cumque necessitatibus odit. Omnis, fugiat officia?</div>
                    <div mat-line> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio voluptatibus, rem blanditiis nobis, nemo, soluta velit molestiae repudiandae vel non atque accusantium ipsum deleniti saepe natus quam quasi quae fuga.</div>
                </mat-list-item>
            </div>
        </mat-list>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.child-1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.child-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child-3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.container {
  margin: 15px;
  height: auto;
  width: 95%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### what i want

I included another container in the next stack blitz that uses the same CSS and flexlayout that works just fine. I want the other container to be the same using mat-list

#### stackblitz

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rc9yw6?file=src/app/app.component.css)